# Google Sheets - using ArrayFormula with Importdata from URL with token to split results by a colon delimiter

Tags: google-sheets, split, delimiter

my query is, to pull data from a url. below is the query i am using;

=ArrayFormula(split(IMPORTDATA("https://profile.<"site_name">.com/api/get_weekly_readings?token="),":"))

It "does" work. but only for the first header,

["readings:6048"] arrays into ["readings | 6048]

but the remaining results to not array. I did notice the the first result listed above, is the only header with quotes ("")

Is this the cause? I hope I provided enough information, and used the correct terminology, I am more familiar with excel, and not much at that. Thanks

Comment: Do you have an example of the data imported, with exactly in the same structure but dummy values (if the real values need to be kept confidential)?

Comment: whats the "site name" ? please provide the full url